# How to echo date from wordpress custom taxonomy field

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 defualt fields (Name, slug, parent, description) in my taxonomy form. But i want to add new field,  to be specific -> date. So i put this code to my functions.php of my theme.

```
function my_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'field' ); ?></label>
        <input type="date" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="">
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','field' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp-type-activity-types_add_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function my_taxonomy_edit_meta_field($term) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $t_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'field' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="date" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) ? esc_attr( $term_meta['custom_term_meta'] ) : ''; ?>">
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','field' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp-type-activity-types_edit_form_fields', 'my_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );
        foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ) {
            if ( isset ( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ) {
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        // Save the option array.
        update_option( "taxonomy_$t_id", $term_meta );
    }
}  
add_action( 'edited_wp-type-activity-types', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_wp-type-activity-types', 'save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Now i am stuck, because dont know how to echo my date.

I can only echo 4 defualt fields (Name, slug, parent, description).

```
$my_desc = get_term_field( 'description', $value->term_id);
echo $my_desc;
```

So why I cant echo my custom field -> date, like that:

```
$my_date = get_term_field( 'term_meta[custom_term_meta]', $value->term_id);
echo $my_date;
```

Comment: i suggest you go through each line of code and try to understand it. You are saving the data into the options table and trying to pull from the terms table, wont work. Also your key would no longer be `term[custom_term_meta]` according to the code above it would simply be `custom_term_meta`. You should probably rewrite the above to use term meta anyway, its new and better than saving data into the options table.

Comment: thank u for your suggestions. :)